# Extract text between two text delimiters (tags)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am terrible with regex and too lazy to learn it (I know, it is bad...) My query

`SELECT regexp_replace('MYSTART1#blah~MYSTART2#blah2~MYSTART3#blah-blah~MYSTART4#blah-blah', '.*MYSTART2#(.+)\~.*', '\1') FROM DUAL;`

Should show the value between `MYSTART2#` and `~`

Result:
`blah2~MYSTART3#blah-blahMYSTART4#blah-blah`

Needs to be `blah2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plus sign operator is "greedy," which means it matches as many characters as possible. Add a question mark to make it lazy instead:

```
'.*MYSTART2#(.+?)\~.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp_substr:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('MYSTART1#blah~MYSTART2#blah2~MYSTART3#blah-blah~MYSTART4#blah-blah', '[^\#\~]+', 1, 2*&mystart_pos) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the greedy cardinality you used. You should use a non-greedy (or lazy) one: `(.+?)`.

For example with the input `aaa#bbb#ccc#ddd`:

- `#.*#` will match `#bbb#ccc#` (greedy)
- `#.*?#` will match `#bbb#` (lazy)